# My Flask-AppBuilder project only display ID for related table, instead of its name, Why?

Tags: flask-appbuilder

I am going to use F.A.B for fast custom IoT APP Web as backend.

By running the sample project of F.A.B tutorial and documents, the http://127.0.0.1:5000/contactmodelview/list/ ContactView list page, the Contact Group is shown as name, in black, instead of id.

[image]

I cloned the design, there is a 1:N relationship (one account has many devices, as same as ContactGroup has many contacts), here is the code:

models.py

```
class Account(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = Column(String(128), unique = True)
    password = Column(String(128))
    email = Column(String(128))
    oauth = Column(String(128))
    cellphone = Column(String(32))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.username

class Device(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    snr = Column(String(256), unique = True)
    name = Column(String(128))
    addr = Column(String(256))
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longitude = Column(Float)
    status = Column(Integer)
    api_id = Column(String(512))
    api_key = Column(String(256))
    api_dev_id = Column(String(256), unique = True)
    api_dev_key = Column(String(256))
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('account.id'))    
    owner = relationship("Account")

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
class DeviceView(ModelView):        
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Device)
    related_views = [ApplicationView, EventView]

    label_columns = {'snr':'SNR', 'api_dev_id':'Device ID', 'owner_id':'Owner'}
    list_columns = ['snr','name','addr','owner_id']

    show_fieldsets = [
    ('Summary',
        {'fields':['snr','name','owner_id']}
    ),
    ('Device Info',
            {'fields':'addr','latitude','longitude','status','api_id','api_key','api_dev_id','api_dev_key'],'expanded':True}
    ),
    ]


class AccountView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Account)
    related_views = [DeviceView]
```

However, the list of DeviceView shows related ID in blue, and No Account name is displayed. However in DeviceDetail view, the Account name is displayed.

[image]

What's the differences?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, and change my view code as following:

```
class DeviceView(ModelView):        
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Device)
    related_views = [ApplicationView, EventView]

    label_columns = {'snr':'SNR', 'api_dev_id':'Device ID', 'owner_id':'Owner'}
    list_columns = ['name','snr','addr','owner']

    show_fieldsets = [
    ('Summary',
        {'fields':['snr','name','owner']}
    ),
    ('Device Info',
        {'fields':['addr','latitude','longitude','status','api_id','api_key','api_dev_id','api_dev_key'],'expanded':True}
    ),
    ]
```

The major differences are replacing field 'owner_id' with 'owner'.